# Suma de totales de un for, dentro de if c++

Tags: c++

mi código pide precios, y muestra los totales con descuento, pero ahora quiero sumar esos totales de cada producto, tengo un for para introducir cuantos artículos son, y dentro de ello, la lectura de los precios que ya incluye descuento, pero quiero ahora, sumar los precios totales, en un total final, este es mi código, funciona bien y todo, solo me falta saber como sumar el todos los precios finales en un total final, gracias amigos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
   int nart=0;
   int precio;
   int total;
   int totalmax;
   cout<<"Numero de articulos? ";
   cin>>nart;
   
   for(int i=1; i<=nart; i++){
       cout<<"Costo del articulo "<<i<<": ";
       cin>>precio;
       if(precio>=200){
           cout<<"Descuento 15%"<<endl;
       total=precio-(precio*0.15);
       }
       if((precio>=100)&&(precio<200)){
        cout<<"Descuento 12%"<<endl;
        total=precio-(precio*0.12);
       }
       cout<<"El precio con descuento es de: "<<total<<endl;
       }
       
     
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
   int nart=0;
   int precio;
   int total;
   int total2
   int totalmax;
   cout<<"Numero de articulos? ";
   cin>>nart;
   
   for(int i=1; i<=nart; i++){
       cout<<"Costo del articulo "<<i<<": ";
       cin>>precio;
       if(precio>=200){
           cout<<"Descuento 15%"<<endl;
       total=precio-(precio*0.15);
       }
       if((precio>=100)&&(precio<200)){
        cout<<"Descuento 12%"<<endl;
        total2=precio-(precio*0.12);
       }
       cout<<"El precio con descuento es de: "<<total+total2<<endl;
       }
       
     
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Intenta redactar mejor tu consulta, ya que no es muy clara, pero segun como lo entendi, seria de esta forma, me avisas si no :)